# "Поджечь конфорку" или "зажечь конфорку"?

Tags: недопустимая-метка, лексическая-сочетаемость

Как правильно:

```
"зажечь конфорку"
```

или

```
"поджечь конфорку"?
```

Answer (score 1):

На этот счет нет единого мнения. Наиболее вероятным кажется объяснение: зажигают то, что может гореть само (зажечь конфорку), а поджигают то, что само собой не горит и поджог требует некоторых усилий (поджечь кучу хвороста).

Answer (score 1):

То, что поджигают, уничтожается огнем, а конфорка остается целой. Её как и лампочку и олимпийский огонь зажигают.